# response of axios retry in main.js in vue js

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a method named `getUsers` and it is in created hook in `Users` Component and I have access token and refresh token in my local storage.

I want that when my token expires, I use refresh token and get new access token and retry last request that was failed because of expired access token.

My problem is I want get response of second try of `axios` call in first `axios` call point (in Users component in created hook) because I fill table from response of it.

How can I do that?

**main.js:**

```js
    axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      config.headers['Content-Type'] = `application/json`;
      config.headers['Accept'] = `application/json`;
      config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`;
      return config;
    }, (err) => {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });

    let getRefreshError = false
    axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        return response
      },
      (error) => {
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        if (!getRefreshError && error.response.status === 401) {
          axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL + process.env.VUE_APP_REFRESH_TOKEN,
            {refresh_token: localStorage.getItem("refresh_token")})
            .then(res => {
              localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data.result.access_token);
              localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", res.data.result.refresh_token);
              originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
              return axios(originalRequest)
                .then((res) => {
                  return Promise.resolve(res);
                }, (err) => {
                return Promise.reject(err);
              });
            }).catch(error => {
            getRefreshError = true;
            router.push('/pages/login')
            return Promise.reject(error);
          })
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

**Users:**

```js
    created() {
         this.getUsers();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return a new Promise from error handler of response interceptor. Refresh token there, perform the original request and resolve promise based on the result of actions (refreshing and re-fetching). Here is a general sketch of what you should do.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (res => res),
  (err => {
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) => {

      // refresh token
        // then save the token
           // then reperform original request
           // and resolve with the response of the original request.

             resolve(resOfSecondRequest)

           // in case of any error, reject with the error
           // and catch it where original call was performed just like the normal flow
             reject(errOfSecondRequest)

    }
  })
)
```

Comment: so whats the difference?

Comment: *I want get response of second try of axios call in first axios call point*

Comment: could you help me the complete code ? im confused with that !! how can i prevent multiple refresh token api call